# Running script in cygwin enviroment

Tags: cygwin

I'm using this code:

```
  numbzip=`ls *.plt.zip | wc -l` &>/dev/null
```

and trying to get rid of the output in the command window.

No files ending on .plt.zip exist so it comes back with:

```
ls: cannot access *.plt.zip: No such file or directory
```

whatever I try it always writes this line in the command window.

I tried:

```
numbzip=`ls *.plt.zip | wc -l` >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
numbzip=`ls *.plt.zip | wc -l` >/dev/null >>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Regards, Wilco.

Comment: If one of the answers you receive solves your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`. Instead use find

```
numbzip=$(find -iname "*.zip" | wc -l)

echo $numzip
```

Comment: Using find in this way has all of the problems that parsing `ls` does. The only reason you'd want to use `find` is because of its `-print0` option which prints null-separated output and can deal correctly with file names containing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You keep seeing the message because you're redirecting the wrong thing:

```
numbzip=`ls *.plt.zip | wc -l` &>/dev/null
```

That redirects the stderr of the variable assignment, not of the `ls` command. You're running the `ls` inside the ``` `` ``` and redirecting outside it. To redirect the error output of `ls`, use:

```
numbzip=`ls *.plt.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
```

That said, while the above will wrk for simple file names, it will fail if your filenames contain newlines. As a general rule, you should [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can use shell globbing instead:

```
zipfiles=( *.plt.zip )
echo ${#zipfiles[@]}
```

The first command will create the `zipfiles` array whose contents are all the files/directories matching the glob `*.plt.zip`. The second line print the number of elements in the array.